# Fix div to the bottom of the screen in Salesforce1 App | Lightning | How to get the visible height excluding Salesforce app components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I wanted to fix a particular div to the bottom of the visible screen in Salesforce1 app using SLDS in Lightning.
Some may find that this particular questions is a [duplicate](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/123176/fixed-div-in-salesforce1-using-lightning-components) of this one.

They've implemented the same in their native functionalities (in Leads, Opportunities, Quotas, Accounts etc.) as shown below

[image]

I would like to implement the same **with locker service enabled**.

Earlier, I used to calculate required height by taking the whole window height and then subtracting it with the top headers height using JavaScript (I am not able to do access the top header now since the locker service has been enabled).